# In Vue 2, is there a way to (temporarily) disable a component from updating computed properties?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that I essentially want to to stay static while things are updating in the parent, and I want to set some kind of boolean to indicate when it's ready to update the component properties.
Thanks!

Comment: I think that if its the parent component who control when to update or not, the computed properties needs to be props that come from the parent. So, when you are ready to update these props, you do so in a parent component method.